# ListFind test conditions

Tags: comparative-review, form, coldfusion, cfml

I am considering

```
        <input type="checkbox" name="arConfig[3]" value="payout"  
            <cfif ListFind(attributes.config[3], "payout") NEQ 0>checked="checked"</cfif>  /> Payout<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="arConfig[3]" value="points"  
            <cfif ListFind(attributes.config[3], "points") NEQ 0>checked="checked"</cfif>  /> Points<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="arConfig[3]" value="quarter" 
            <cfif ListFind(attributes.config[3], "quarter") NEQ 0>checked="checked"</cfif>  /> Quarter<br />
```

Vs

```
        <input type="checkbox" name="arConfig[3]" value="payout"  
             <cfif ListFind(attributes.config[3], "payout") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>  /> Payout<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="arConfig[3]" value="points"  
             <cfif ListFind(attributes.config[3], "points") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>  /> Points<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="arConfig[3]" value="quarter" 
             <cfif ListFind(attributes.config[3], "quarter") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>  /> Quarter<br />
```

Which is clearer the `NEQ 0` or the `GT 0` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't care what the numeric value here is, so don't test for it. You want a boolean, and I think the `listFind()` call is semantically boolean itself without the comparison.

So: "neither". Do this instead:

```
<cfif ListFind(attributes.config[3], "payout")>
```

Either/any option looks pretty cluttered as it is, so given yer repeating the same string except for the difference of the `value`, I'd put that lot in a loop over the values too, maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Just a note: As a personal rule for booleans, I've always found it better to check for NOT FALSE rather than a TRUE value (though in this situation, I 100% agree with Adam's answer). FALSE will pretty much always be a 0, but TRUE can be anything not 0. ( You'd think that Microsoft could have coordinated its definition of TRUE between SQL Server and Access. :-S )

Comment: Good point.  Forgetting that most non-zero values equate to true can easily lead to inadvertent logic errors. That said, I still prefer expressing conditionals in the positive (if feasible) :-). It is just more natural and intuitive IMO.

Comment: @Leigh I completely agree with it being more natural to look at a true value. However, I've been smacked before looking for true when I had people editing values in a SQL Server database with an Access interface. I didn't know they were using Access, so it was fun figuring out how my "boolean"s were getting flipped to -1 instead of 1. Though that problem is likely as much to do with bad initial db setup. We had big discussions about why a boolean field should be a bit instead of a nullable int. :-/